# Transferring times from one sheet to another - which dim option?

Tags: excel, vba, time, transfer

I have been working on the following code to automate data transfer from one sheet to another; however I am stuck on how to write the time element. The time would be in format hh:mm and would be transferred in the same format. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
    Private Sub Commandbutton1_Click()

    Dim Dateadded As Date
    Dim Time As ???
    Dim nameoftask As String
    Dim typeoftask As String
    Dim Iffollowupwhichtaskisitfollowing As String
    Dim Howwastaskcommunicated As String
    Dim Whowastaskcommunicatedto As String
    Dim Whorequestedtask As String
    Dim Whatistaskrequiredfor As String
    Dim Descriptionoftask As String
    Dim Deadlinefortask As Date
    Dim myData As Workbook

    Worksheets("sheet1").Select
    Dateadded = Range("b5")
    Time = Range("b7")
    nameoftask = Range("b9")
    typeoftask = Range("b11")
    Iffollowupwhichtaskisitfollowing = Range("b13")
    Howwastaskcommunicated = Range("b15")
    Whorequestedtask = Range("b17")
    Whatistaskrequiredfor = Range("b19")
    Descriptionoftask = Range("b21")
    Deadlinefortask = Range("b23")

    Set myData = Workbooks.Open("filelink")
    Worksheets("sheet1").Select
    Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a1").Select
    RowCount = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    With Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a1")
    .Offset(RowCount, 1) = Date
    .Offset(RowCount, 2) = Time
    .Offset(RowCount, 3) = nameoftask
    .Offset(RowCount, 4) = typeoftask
    .Offset(RowCount, 5) = Iffollowupwhichtaskisitfollowing
    .Offset(RowCount, 6) = Howwastaskcommunicated
    .Offset(RowCount, 7) = Whowastaskcommunicatedto
    .Offset(RowCount, 8) = Whorequestedtask
    .Offset(RowCount, 9) = Whatistaskrequiredfor
    .Offset(RowCount, 10) = Descriptionoftask
    .Offset(RowCount, 11) = Deadlinefortask
    End With
    myData.Save
    End Sub
```

Comment: [Date](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/3418/data-types-and-limits/11783/date#t=201609132226475078262) will store either a date or time.  It's how Excel stores them natively.

Answer (score 0):

If you dim the time variable as a Date, the cell format will make it across with your approach.

If the time is stored and displaying in the cell as a time value, its underlying data type is a decimal number less than 1. So you could also dim it as a double.

The format will not come across to the new cell if you use a double in your current code, though, just the cell value. You would need to format the target cell with your preferred time format.

So, Date is the data type you want to dim to.